# How do i implement the Search button on Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, search, button

I'm quite new to Xcode. I'm building a basic app that searches a website. Ive got the search button to work with a Go button at the side. How would i make the search button also respond to the search on the bottom right on the keyboard?

```
@IBAction func didClickGo(AnyObject) {
        var text = textField.text
        var url = NSURL.URLWithString("http://www.mysite.co.uk/search?controller=search&orderby=position&orderway=desc&search_query="+text)
        var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        webView.loadRequest(request)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22178145/4014757

First, in your view controller you can assign a delegate for the search bar (probably also your view controller)

```
 searchBar.delegate = this;
```

Then in your view controller (the delegate), you can override the searchBarSearchButtonClicked method with whatever you want to do when the search button is pressed.

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
```

Hope this is what you're looking for, good luck.

Comment: Would that work in Swift (sorry, forgot to mention that in the title)